# C# Create plugins with their own settings

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

I wish to provide each plugin (using MEF) with its own settings configuration
that will be exposed through the consumer applications UI.

My first idea would be to include a json file in the plugin with all the possible settings and create a matching class + interface. When the plugin is imported the settings file would be parsed and all the settings dynamically laid out on its configuration page?

Is there anyone that already has some experience with this?
Care to point me in the right direction? :)

Thank you!

Comment: Property grids.  They use reflection to edit public properties on types.  Look into them.

Comment: @Will I know about property grids. I used them before but I need something more flexible.

Comment: You can expose UI through MEF.  So the plugin publisher could publish their own editor as well?  Haven't done it before, but IIRC that's how Visual Studio does it.

Comment: I want to avoid including UI elements in a plugin assembly. The settings should be pure logic and my main app should present per plugin settings. I was thinking data templates or styles to represent the settings class included in a plugin but I'm not sure how to maintain the most dynamic way to present each plugins specific settings..